# user to user notification message with ionic app using Frirebase cloud Messaging

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, http-post, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notifications from my ionic app using Firebase cloud messaging. I installed FCM Plugin by following the steps below:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm

npm install --save @ionic-native/fcm
```

And up to there, everything works fines. I am using **http plugin of ionic native** to send notification via the **FCM rest api** using a **post request**. So I installed the **http plugin** with the following commands:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http

npm install --save @ionic-native/http
```

And I included **FCM and HTTP modules** in my **app.modules.ts**
In one of my controllers, here is how I send the post request:

```
this.http.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
    {
        "notification": {
            "title": "Notification title",
            "body": "Notification body"
        },
        "data": {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2"
        },
        "to": "/topics/all",
        "priority": "high"
    },
    {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "key=serverkey"
    }
).catch(error=>{
  alert(error.error);
})
```

I took the serverkey value from **firebase console**. So when I send the post request no error messages are displayed but no notifications are sent.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: I am trying exactly the same thing, but I do get an error message, which is:

JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected character (d) at position 0.

Comment: @macduff According to me, the best way to send notification using firebase is to use firebase cloud functions. it is quite simple and more efficient than using the http plugin and the FCM rest api. Its the solution i finaly used. And the notification is sent correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following before your post so that the object arguments are encoded as JSON

```
this.http.setDataSerializer("json")
```

This solved my problem (see comment)